# MFC Focusing on the first field of my Input Box

Tags: input, mfc, focus, highlight, box

I'm a beginner in MFC and I just want my input box selected by default, ready to input text with the keyboard when the input box pops up.

Here is my C++ .cpp file of the class:

```cpp
testInputBox::testInputBox(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_INPUT_BOX, pParent)
    , warning(_T(""))
{

}

testInputBox::~testInputBox()
{
}

void testInputBox::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT_INPUT_BOX, editcedit);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_STATIC_MESSAGE, warning);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, warning, 100);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(testInputBox, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT_INPUT_BOX, &testInputBox::OnEnChangeEdit1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &testInputBox::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &testInputBox::OnBnClickedCancel)
    ON_STN_CLICKED(IDC_STATIC_MESSAGE, &testInputBox::OnStnClickedStaticMessage)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: The system sets input focus to the first control in tab order in a dialog. You don't have to do anything for that to work. See [How to: Define Control Access and Values (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/defining-mnemonics-access-keys).

Comment: @IInspectable That was my initial thought on the subject. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the [`OnInitDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170#oninitdialog) member of the `CDialogEx` class and, in that override, set the focus to the desired control. Then, because you *have* explicitly set the focus, your override function should return zero (or `FALSE`).

Assuming your `editcedit` is a pointer to the control you wish to have the focus, then your override will look something like this:

```cpp
BOOL testInputBox::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog(); // Always call base class function
    // ... anything else you want to do here
    editcedit->SetFocus(); // Or: GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_INPUT_BOX)->SetFocus();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Your override should be declared in the class like this:

```cpp
class testInputBox : public CDialogEx
{
//...
protected:
    BOOL OnInitDialog() override;
    //...
};
```

Comment: [How to set focus in a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283).

Comment: @IInspectable A decent article, as would be expected considering the author. However, in this case, OP has explicitly stated that the focus is being set to an **edit control**, so the issues raised by Raymond about setting it explicitly to a (non-default) button don't really apply. Point taken, though.

Comment: Calling `SetFocus` still has the opportunity of losing all keyboard input (see [Never leave focus on a disabled control](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040804-00/?p=38243)).

Comment: I suppose another alternative is to set the tab order (if appropriate) so that the first control is the one the user wants. Personally, I use `GotoDlgCtrl` as per the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`CDialog::GotoDlgCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170#gotodlgctrl) is what you search.

```
BOOL testInputBox::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog(); 
    // ... 

    GotoDlgCtrl(&editcedit);  

    // alternativ
    CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_INPUT_BOX)
    if(pWnd)
       GotoDlgCtrl(pWnd)
    // ...
```

}

Comment: `GoToDkgCtrl` is what I use.

Comment: That won't compile, since it's leaving out the return value. That could be excused in cases where the value is obvious. In this case it isn't, and picking the right one is **crucial** to the functioning of the implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable let’s assume the …. Comment includes return statement. 